# Не срабатывает shell_exec в php , а если запускаешь отдельно в командной строке срабатывает

Tags: php, linux, bash

Не срабатывает shell_exec , а если запускаешь отдельно в командной строке срабатывает.

```
$var2 = "ps axf | grep 'ffmpeg -i rtmp://domen.ru/live/nicvik' | grep -v grep | awk '{print \"kill -9 \" $1}' | sh ";
echo shell_exec($var2);
```

Более того, если я запускаю например

```
$var2 = "ps axf | grep 'ffmpeg -i rtmp://domen.ru/live/nicvik' | grep -v grep | awk '{print \"kill -9 \" $1}';
```

То он выводи pid, но при запуске с | sh процессы не убиваются.

Comment: `pkill -9 -f 'ffmpeg -i rtmp://domen.ru/live/nicvik'`

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация из командной строки работает, а в файле php нет :(

Comment: да это я вам не про программу php, а про то что вы где-то в интернете, видимо, нашли. // а по поводу программы php: вы же программист, разбирайтесь, чего этой программе не хватает. отладочный вывод — друг программиста. ну и не забывайте, что помимо stdout есть ещё и stderr.

Comment: да, случайно обнаружилась программа php на одном из компьютеров, потому проверил: в одном процессе оболочки запустил `$ sleep 100`, в другом благополучно этот процесс убил: `$ php -r "shell_exec(\"pkill -f 'sleep 100'\");"`. именно при посредстве программы php.

Comment: Ну а разве вы от одного и того же пользователя запускаете эти варианты? 99% с правами намудрили, ну и см. первый комментарий Баракина на тему как сделать проще.

Comment: Нет, от разных, но сути это не меняет. За упрощённый вариант спасибо, но проблема не решена. Как я понимаю тут проблема с правами запуска программы. Когда я запускаю через командную строку, процесс убивается так как я root, а если это происходит при запуске через php, ничего не происходит , так как я не root. Поэтому все комментарии, которые указаны выше бесполезны,  к сожалению .